# Symfony 4.3 project is not started

Tags: php, symfony4

First of all - sorry for my bad english.
I'm new to Symfony, and right now I'm working on authorization form.
What I've done and what I've got:

1. Create an auth form with `php bin/console make:auth`
2. Customize the twig file and routes;
3. But forgot about route for successful authorization;
4. After I've tried to log in with some dummy data (created with `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load`), my project got freezed;
5. After restarting server (Ctrl+C in command line, and then `php bin/console server:run`), I've got this error message in `dev.log`:

> php.DEBUG: Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или
>   было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика
>   уже подключенного компьютера. ) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\SilencedErrorContext:
>   {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"D:\\OpenServer\\OSPanel\\domains\\ParkingApp_Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\web-server-bundle\\WebServerConfig.php\",\"line\":141,\"trace\":[{\"file\":\"D:\\OpenServer\\OSPanel\\domains\\ParkingApp_Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\web-server-bundle\\WebServerConfig.php\",\"line\":54,\"function\":\"findBestPort\",\"class\":\"Symfony\\Bundle\\WebServerBundle\\WebServerConfig\",\"type\":\"->\"}],\"count\":1})"}
>   []

6. I've tried `php bin/console cache:clear` - it didn't help;

About server:

- I'm using `OpenServer 5.2.2`;
- `Apache_2.4`;
- `PHP 7.2`;
- `MySQL 5.7`;
- `Symfony 4.3.3`

Hope someone will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try and translate "Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера"?

Comment: Something like that (machine translating): **The attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful, because the required response was not received from another computer in the required time, or the already established connection was terminated due to the incorrect response of the already connected computer**